# Read image on iPhone from C++

Tags: c++, ios, swift

I am working on a C++ library that shall do image processing. My approach now is to pass two strings to C++ from swift. One string is the path to the image and the second is the output directory.

All the time I get that the file does not exist. How can I get the correct path the asset? The image lies in a directory I have created on my own and is called "test.jpg". I also have a "test2.jpg" in Assets. Have not managed to find that either.

Swift Code:

```
func getGrayImage() -> Image {
    if var resourcePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "jpg") {
        let dir = resourcePath.deletingLastPathComponent()
        VideoProcessingWrapper().rgb2gray(resourcePath.absoluteString, dir.absoluteString)
    }
    return Image("test2")
}
```

C++ Code:

```
void VideoProcessing::rgb2gray(const std::string& image_path, const std::string& dir) {
  std::cout << "C++: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << image_path << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << dir << std::endl;
  std::cout << "In directory: " <<std::endl;
  for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir)) {
        std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
  }
  if (std::filesystem::exists(image_path)) {
    std::cout << "File exists" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "File does NOT exist" << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  cv::imread(image_path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
}
```

It even crashes when trying to display all files in the directory, stating that the directory does not exist. But what have I then been given from `Bundle.main.url`-call?

This is the printout from the C++ function using a simulator:

```
C++: 
file:///Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F438661-8BF5-4A60-B41F-1D4B7FEC6A8E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AB3EFF3E-79A4-469C-A3BF-ABDD31A09E61/TestVideoProcess.app/test.jpg

file:///Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F438661-8BF5-4A60-B41F-1D4B7FEC6A8E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AB3EFF3E-79A4-469C-A3BF-ABDD31A09E61/TestVideoProcess.app/
```

I get the same behaviour when running on a real iPhone.

Comment: Instead of resourcePath.absoluteString use resourcePath.path and instead of dir.absoluteString use dir.path.

Comment: why reinvent the bicycle if Swift already has at least 3 ways to manipulate image: CI Filters, Accelerate, and Metal?

Comment: Using `.path`is enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Foundation` framework represents paths with [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)'s, while C++ standard library filesystem relies on more file-path-specific format [which may consist of only the following components](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path):

> 1. `root-name(optional)`: identifies the root on a filesystem with multiple roots (such as `"C:"` or `"//myserver"`). In case of
>    ambiguity, the longest sequence of characters that forms a valid
>    root-name is treated as the root-name. The standard library may define
>    additional root-names besides the ones understood by the OS API.
> 2. `root-directory(optional)`: a directory separator that, if present, marks this path as absolute. If it is missing (and the first
>    element other than the root name is a file name), then the path is
>    relative and requires another path as the starting location to resolve
>    to a file name.
> 3. Zero or more of the following:
>
> - `file-name`: sequence of characters that aren't directory separators or preferred directory separators (additional limitations
>   may be imposed by the OS or file system). This name may identify a
>   file, a hard link, a symbolic link, or a directory. Two special
>   file-names are recognized:
> - `dot`: the file name consisting of a single dot character `.` is a directory name that refers to the current directory dot-dot: the file
>   name consisting of two dot characters `..` is a directory name that
>   refers to the parent directory.
> - `directory-separators`: the forward slash character `/` or the alternative character provided as path::preferred_separator. If this
>   character is repeated, it is treated as a single directory separator:
>   `/usr///////lib` is the same as `/usr/lib`

A URI consists of quite [a lot of different parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#/media/File:URI_syntax_diagram.svg):
[image]

In this case you need the `path` part only. One trick you can employ here is to build the path from [`pathComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780324-pathcomponents) of the `URL` instance:

```swift
if let resourcePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "jpg") {
    let dir = resourcePath.deletingLastPathComponent()
    VideoProcessingWrapper().rgb2gray(resourcePath.pathComponents.joined(separator: "/"),
                                      dir.pathComponents.joined(separator: "/"))

}
```

Alternatively, as suggested by [**mani** in the comments to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73591452/read-image-on-iphone-from-c/73593559#comment129955014_73591452), you can use the [`path`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779812-path) property of the same class, however the documentation says that it also may include parameter string and for some reason it's now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, the bundle directory is inside your application and you have no write access to it.

Comment: While this is correct, the code snippet provided by OP doesn't write anything to the bundle directory

Comment: And I have successfully read and written and image and read that image again in SwiftUI. The key was to use .path